# Entering complex URLs in Markdown syntax?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

Is the problem me, or Stack Overflow?

If I post a comment or question with this named link, some text, and then an inline link *the preview will show correctly* but the actual result is strange.  All of the text from the start of the first link up to and including the text of the second link is linked to the first destination.

For example:

```
[strfriend](http://strfriend.com/) is *your* friend:

<http://strfriend.com/vis?re=%28Zip%3A%5cs%2a%5cd%5cd%5cd%5cd%5cd%29%5cs%2a%28State%3A%5cs%2a%5cw%5cw%29>
```

Results in:

[strfriend](http://strfriend.com/) is *your* friend:

http://strfriend.com/vis?re=%28Zip%3A%5cs%2a%5cd%5cd%5cd%5cd%5cd%29%5cs%2a%28State%3A%5cs%2a%5cw%5cw%29

Notice how the entire first line is linked, and how the second link actually points to the destination of the first.

> #### Related:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217533/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses

Comment: Can you show your exact markup, and perhaps provide a screenshot?  Your description is hard to follow.

Comment: I have the syntax in a code block in the question, and the result can be seen right below it (the 'bug' is visible in Firefox 3, IE 6, the iPhone's Safari, and probably other browsers...).  Do I really need a screenshot?

Comment: The wierd thing is that the edit preview gets it right!

Comment: I had this problem a few days ago, and the person who fixed it changed the links at the bottom of the page (the text "[1] href"). In my case, the problem occurred when I inserted a new link before an existing one.

Answer (score 7):

**Updated in light of comment:**

```
[strfriend][1] is *your* friend

  [1]: http://strfriend.com/
```

Results in:

[strfriend](http://strfriend.com/) is *your* friend

Comment: I want the word `strfriend ` to be a link and not the rest of the sentence.  I could user the reference-style links, but shouldn't the code I posted be valid syntax?  The preview pane even gets it right!

Comment: Updated in light of your comment...  The syntax you have above isn't valid Markdown, at least not on here on SO.

Comment: MarkDown is just ambiguous this way because valid links could actually contain parentheses. Your solution is good.

Comment: @James It's not valid Markdown?  That format for links is shown as an example right on the edit page in the "Formatting Help" box...

Answer (score 4):

Escape the parens. Parens are pretty toxic in URLs.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001181.html

It's even worse: those strfriend URLs in the form of

`http://strfriend.com/vis?re=(Zip%3A\s*\d\d\d\d\d)\s*(State%3A\s*\w\w)`

...are *really* painful. You'll have to encode almost everything in it. See my edit. Works now, but not worth it IMO.

str **friend**? more like str **ENEMY**.

Comment: That does work, thanks.  It still seems odd that it would render correctly in the preview but not in the final version.  Well, maybe not odd if they use different Markdown rendering engines.

Comment: Parentheses in URLs might be toxic, but they're also perfectly valid, and thus the syntax ought to work.

Comment: A URL this crazy should be tinyurl'ed IMO